# Change UILabel/UIButton text from an array of strings with time and animation

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel

What would be the best method for taking a `UILabel` or `UIButton` element, and having the text change at some set time frame, say 3 seconds with the contents of an array collection of strings with fade animation?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `NSTimer` to schedule the text change. For example, if your method was called `changeText`, you can start a timer by using `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self 
select:@selector(changeText) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`, where `3.0` is the time interval in seconds.

As for the animation, you have two options. You can have the text fade out and then fade in, or you can have the text fade from one string to the next. To do the former (fade in then out), use something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    textLabel.alpha = 0.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    textLabel.text = newString;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        textLabel.alpha = 1.0f;
    }];
}];
```

This fades out the text label in 0.5 seconds (by setting alpha to 0), then sets the text to newString and fades the label back in.

Alternatively, to have the text fade from one value to the other:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
animation.duration = 1.00;
[textLabel.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"kCATransitionFade"];
textLabel.text = newString;
```

Comment: @Diamond The code goes in the function that the timer executes. In my example, it would be called `changeText`, so you would declare a method like `-(void)changeText { ... }`

Comment: Sorry, I meant that only the animation code should be added to the `changeText` method. You should start the timer when your view loads (`viewDidLoad`). My code also does not include selecting the text string from your array - that should also go in `changeText`. However, I will point out that StackOverflow is not a place to request people to write blocks of code for you. If you're not sure about Objective-C and iOS SDK basics, perhaps look up some beginner tutorials. There is lots of info on timers, animations/fading text, and randomising strings - on SO and elsewhere.